# WordPress: How to display specific layout contents at different locations of the page?

Tags: wordpress, layout, frontend, content-management-system, advanced-custom-fields

We are using your Advanced Custom Fields plug-in which by default provides a custom field group called **Flexible Content Template**. I'm trying to develop a new webpage with a new group of custom fields that is created only for this page named **B2B landing page**. A couple of sections in this page can be created by using an existing layouts called **"Icon Columns"** and "text and full image" from Flexible Content Template custom fields group. Question is how can I access the contents of these two layouts separately in the template file so that they are displayed when I need them to? Why I'm asking this is because in our project I see that we display flexible content field data with this line `<?php get_template_part('template-parts/fields/field--flex-content'); ?>` This brings contents from the Flexible Content field everywhere you call this function, not just the specific layout data meant for the section. I need to be able to display contents selectively. Below is the code for you to have a look and see if you can suggest some solution.

```
<!-- START HERO -->
<?php
$hero = get_field('hero');
$hero_h1 = $hero['hero_-_h1'];
$hero_h2 = $hero['hero_-_h2'];
$background = $hero['hero_-_background_options'];
$image = $background['background_-_image'];
$link = $hero['cta'];
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="corp-hero relative mb-row">
  
  <?php if($image): ?>
  <div class="corp-hero-img relative no-touch select-none">
    <picture>
      <source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['small']); ?>">
      <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['medium']); ?>">
      <source media="(max-width: 1280px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['large']); ?>">
      <source srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['xlarge']); ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo($image['sizes']['xlarge']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
    </picture>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  
  <div class="wrap-x">
    <div class="inside">

      <?php if(stripos($hero_h1, "Do Not Display") === FALSE): ?>
      <h1 class="mb0 color-tan-dark">
        <?php if( $hero_h1 ): echo $hero_h1; else: echo get_the_title(); endif; ?>
      </h1>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if( $hero_h2 ): ?>
      <h2 class="mb0 mt2 alt-heading h4">
        <?php echo $hero_h2; ?>
      </h2>
      <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
  </div>

  <?php if ( $link ) : ?>
    <div class="inside mt2x">
        <div class="center-xs">
        <a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" class="btn cta-btn-purple" role="button" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>" title="<?php echo $link['title']; ?>">
            <?php echo $link['title']; ?>
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
<!-- END HERO -->


<!-- START FAST, EASY ORDERING SECTION -->
// I need to only display contents from 'icon-columns' layout
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/fields/field--flex-content'); ?>
<!-- END FAST, EASY ORDERING SECTION -->

<!-- START HOW OUR GIFTS MAKE A SIGNIFICANT IMPACT Section -->
// I need to only display contents from 'text and full image' layout
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/fields/field--flex-content'); ?>
<!-- END HOW OUR GIFTS MAKE A SIGNIFICANT IMPACT Section -->
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading the ACF documentation on the Flexible Content field. I've used it before and it's fairly straightforward 

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/

Comment: Thanks, I'm going through the documentation. In the meanwhile I updated the post to add more information to the context. Please have a look back.

Comment: Yeah, you need to review the documentation. In your code, you need to be checking for the specific layout and then grabbing the sub fields, for that layout. I'd recommend starting with the example code in the documentation and building off that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the tips, which is exactly what I already did during first half of the day. Grateful to you.